# How to write test doubles for Windows API calls that pass arguments by address

Tags: c++, unit-testing, pointers, mocking

I have a number of working mock classes that replace actual calls to the Windows API.  However, I am struggling to put together something for a function that utilises `FormatMessageW` when using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` flag.

When using the `FormatMessageW` function I am first declaring my buffer as follows:

```
wchar_t * buffer = nullptr;
```

I then pass the buffer by address as the `lpBuffer` argument (expected type is `LPWSTR`):

```
reinterpret_cast<::LPWSTR>(&buffer)
```

The Windows API function will automatically create a buffer of the correct size.

I go on further with the buffer by stripping out line breaks, converting from wide characters to multibyte characters etc.

In order to fully unit test the clean up of the output buffer I am attempting to mock the `FormatMessageW` call by having the function simply return a predefined string (which will be a member of the mock object).

To simplify the problem, the following code attempts to replicate my problem:

```
// represents my mock class
class mocker
{

public:
    // takes a wchar_t pointer and attempts to reassign it
    int mockFunction(wchar_t * buffer)
    {
        // assigns local copy of wchar_t pointer!
        buffer = &message[0];

        return message.length();
    }

protected:

    std::wstring message = L"test";
};

// test code
mocker mocking;
wchar_t * buffer = nullptr;
auto size = mocking.mockFunction(&buffer);

// at this point buffer is still null
// but I want the buffer to point to L"test"
```

Is there a way to achieve my aim of redirecting the pointer to an existing `std::wstring` without changing anything but the implementation of `int mockFunction(wchar_t * buffer)`?

Comment: What's a "test double"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - fakes, stubs, mocks etc

Comment: Your prototype is wrong to modify pointer `buffer`, it should be `int mockFunction(wchar_t *& buffer)` or `int mockFunction(wchar_t ** buffer)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - the function I am trying to mock uses the argument `LPWSTR buffer` which is simply `wchar_t * buffer`.   The Windows API somehow spits out a populated buffer from this argument, which is what I am also attempting to achieve.  Is there another way without changing the signature?

Comment: According to [FormatMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx), `buffer` is already allocated memory (which will be filled), not a output pointer. You have to copy inside `buffer`, not reassign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is probably the use of this method with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` option. You can find sample use of this option here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256348

it looks as follows:

```
HLOCAL pBuffer;   // Buffer to hold the textual error description.
// .... 
ret = FormatMessage( 
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | // Function will handle memory allocation.
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | // Using a module's message table.
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
                hInst, // Handle to the DLL.
                dwErrorMsgId, // Message identifier.
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language.
                (LPTSTR)&pBuffer, // Buffer that will hold the text string.
                ERRMSGBUFFERSIZE, // Allocate at least this many chars for pBuffer.
                NULL // No insert values.
                    );
```

`HLOCAL` is defined as `typedef HANDLE HLOCAL;`, and `HANDLE` is `typedef void *HANDLE;`. So what in above example `&pBuffer` returns pointer to pointer, and then casts it to LPTSTR which also is a pointer. Inside FormatMessage a check is done whether FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER is used, and if so then `buffer` parameter is casted like that (probably), `HLOCAL* pToAllocBuffer = reinterpret_cast<HLOCAL*>(buffer)`, and later on `*pToAllocBuffer = LocalAlloc(.....)`.

So, inside your mockFunction you would have to do such ugly casting too, first:

```
wchar_t * buffer = nullptr;
auto size = mocking.mockFunction(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t * >(&buffer));
```

and inside `mockFunction`:

```
wchar_t ** buffer = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t ** >(buffer);
```

now you can allocate memory to buffer like that:

```
*buffer = [HERE YOUR ALLOCATION];
```

dont do this:

> // assigns local copy of wchar_t pointer...

if you will assign local copy, it will be freed on function return, you must use `new`.

Comment: I forgot to mention the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER ` flag in my question, but you are correct in that is exactly what I was trying to replicate.  Where you say "and inside `mockFunction` I went for `wchar_t ** bufferPointer = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t ** >(buffer);`, and my allocation as `*bufferPointer = &message[0];` (rather than attempting to reassign the `buffer` parameter directly).  Other than that your approach solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **marcinj's** answer I was able to achieve my aim by using the following implementation:

```
int mockFunction(wchar_t * buffer)
{
    wchar_t ** bufferPointer = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t **>(buffer);
    *bufferPointer = &message[0];

    return message.length();
}
```

When I implemented this into the working mock class I replaced `wchar_t *` with `LPWSTR`.